# Kendo Grid (javascript) - Filter Option trim input

Tags: kendo-grid, telerik-grid

When using the column menu, users are complaining that their filters don't work because the grid is not trimming their input (eg. Hit column menu, filter-> Starts With -> user types input -> (NEEDS TRIM) -> Profit)

Is there a simple way without digging around in the guts of the grid to trim that input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the Grid [filter event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filter), and manipulate the value of the filter as necessary, e.g.:

http://dojo.telerik.com/opEte